# When and why oracle indexes become invalid?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I always thought B-tree indexes are always updated (rebalanced) after each insert, update or delete. However it looks like Oracle does not update it after deletes ([deleted leafs still remain in index tree](https://blogs.oracle.com/sysdba/entry/when_to_rebuild_index)). How about inserting and updating the rows where we use B-tree index type? Does index is updated during each insert/update?

The other question is why and when indexes become invalid so they needed to be rebuilt? I'm mostly concerned about B-tree indexes, but also would be interesting to know when other types of indexes must be rebuild.

Comment: Deletions from a b-tree index do not cause the leaf blocks to be merged together when they have sufficient space free, but when a leaf block is completely empty it is then returned to the "empty block" list for re-use. Also, a space introduced by deletion from an index leaf block is available for re-use by other suitable rows, so it's not dead space until the index is rebuilt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under normal operation indexes don't become invalid in Oracle.

And they rarely if ever need a "rebuild" either. Ssee this [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2913600659112) article for details. [Jonathan Lewis' blog](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/category/oracle/indexing/index-rebuilds/) also contains very useful information regarding this topic:

The only possible ways I can think of that an index gets invalid is when it has been disabled manually (`alter index foo disable`) or when data was loaded through direct path inserts e.g. when using SQL*Loader with the `direct=true` option.

Edit:

Of course I forgot partitioning. And Winfried is right with his answer.

Comment: @Ben: what exactly do you mean with "table rebuild"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name All the data is written/read using smallest logical unit - oracle blocks. So, we need to set correct PCTFREE when creating tables, depending how much table data is expecting to change. Now, index data is also stored in oracle blocks and it's also possible to set PCTFREE for an index explicitly. How increasing table data size affects index storage inside blocks? If index leave nodes are written into blocks sequentially then how the index is balanced when leave node blocks get filled?

Comment: @Centurion: please don't create new questions as comments. Create a new question for that (that one should probably go to http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

An index gets invalid when you have a partitionized table with global index and you drop one partition from that table. However, when you drop a partition you can specify an implicit rebuild of the index.

Comment: I did not test and I am not sure, but perhaps an index get also invalid when you alter the data type of a column where an index is defined on. Maybe only for composite indexes, i.e. index defined on more than one column only.